# How to handle individual socket.io client events in python?

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am primarily a Javascript developer but I am trying to replicate a server I wrote in Node.js in Python. The server uses Socket.io to communicate with clients and I am having some trouble replicating this specific behaviour in Python:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){ });
});
```

I would like to handle each client's events and messages separately from one another. Any way I could do this in Python? I am using the package **flask_socketio** to wrap the sockets. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you just want connection and disconnection handlers?

You can do that as follows in Python:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    # your connection logic here


@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    # your disconnection logic here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Hi Miguel, not exactly. I would like to handle each client's connection with the server separately. The disconnect logic as well as the subsequent message logic should be tied to each individual client. In your example, as I understand it, the disconnect logic is not client specific but rather global. Meaning that the logic does not know which client disconnected or sent the message etc.

Comment: The client specific data is always accessible in the user session, so your handler logic can do different things depending on data that you have associated with each client when they connected or during the life of the connection. Using per-client handlers is something that feels "normal" in JavaScript, but not so much in Python, where use of inner functions is rare.